# how to create a object and return to js in C++ use v8

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

js code like this

```
var test = testfactory.creat();
test.send({'xxx'});
test.onopen = function() {
    console.log('onopen');
}
```

c++ code like this

```
class testfactory {
public:
    mytest* creat() {
        reutrn new mytest();
   }
}
        

class mytest {
public:
    void send();
    void onopen();
}
```

so, how to create a object and return to js use google v8?

Comment: are the processes running on same machine? do you have a protocol between the processes, like http?

Comment: run on the same machine. in same process. use google v8

Answer (score 0):

Please try reading the official documentation, which explains this: https://v8.dev/docs/embed